# How to do a partial copy/paste recordset

Tags: ms-access, record

Under **MS Access 2013**, I want to copy a record to a new one or an existing record.
I wonder if it is possible to do a partial copy/paste.

Here is my simple example of my DataSet:

```
PayID   PAyDate     PeriodeName EmployeeID  Income  Taxes
001     2019/01/02  1           5           1500    201
002     2019/01/15  2           5           1500    201
003     2019/01/30  3           5           1500    201
004     2019/02/06  4           5           
005     2019/02/06  5           5
```

Please note that

- my complete datasheet has 12 fields which must be copied)
- PayID is an autoNumber

I would like to be able to:

1. copy/paste Income and Taxes fields to an existing record (ex: PayId#3 to payId#4 )
2. copy/paste Income and Taxes fields to a new record (ex: PayId#3 to a new one, ie #6)

I already have a contextual menu in my datasheet with the standard copy paste command buttons but I don't know how to substitute them for a partial copy paste command.

What should I have as OnAction Callback functions?

- callBackCopy()
- callBackPaste()

Thanks for the support.

Comment: You don't need anything special. Just select the matching range (same columns as copy source) in the new or target record before pressing Ctrl+V.

Comment: it is not a copy past in Excel but in Access. If I am right in acces I am not able to select a specific range but I can only select a full row. So your suggestion do not work.

Comment: Can select consecutive fields and not full row for copy/paste manually but not programmatically. An option is to set variables, move to new record row, and use variables to populate fields.

Comment: If you haven't tried what you can do with Copy&Paste in an Access datasheet, you will be surprised. You can do ranges of columns and rows (and both), as long as the selected target range matches the columns.

Comment: Andre : I checked but I can not select range of columns (as in excel). Perhaps because I am running with Access 2013 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not be obvious, but you can Copy&Paste ranges of columns and rows (and both) in an Access datasheet. This works in Access 2010 and 2016, so I assume it works in 2013 too.

You need to move the mouse cursor to the edge of a cell, so it becomes a "+" icon.

Here is a sample video: https://i.imgur.com/H1VHIlo.mp4
(German Access, but you will get the idea)

It shows copying 2x2 cells into new records. You can do the same to overwrite existing records, then you must select the matching number of rows as copy target.

Comment: Thanks for your tips. It is so clearly explain within your video!! I do not know that it was possible and so simple.